# Getting crazy with angular directive and scope update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying for 7 hours now to get something so work and currently I'm pulling my hair out!!!!
Unbelievable!
I just want to update an controller variable from an isolated directive.
And the crazy thing is, in the view everything works perfect, but in the controller he does not recognize the change!

The controller looks like this, because he is generated by TypeScript.

```
/*
ANGULAR CONTROLLER
*/

var CustomerdataTabCtrl = (function () {
    function CustomerdataTabCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.AddressAutocompleteOptions = {};
        $scope.AddressAutocompleteOptions.watchEnter = true;
        $scope.AddressAutocompleteDetails = '';
        $scope.AddressAutocompleteAddress = null;

        $scope.onRoleChange = function () {
            if ($scope.Role == 'Provider') {
                $('#orders-tab-header').css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                $('#orders-tab-header').css('display', 'block');
            }
        };

        $scope.onAddressAutocompleteChange = function () {
            alert('asd');
        };

        $scope.$watch('Role', function () {
            return $scope.onRoleChange();
        }, true);
        $scope.$watch('AddressAutocompleteAddress', function () {
            return $scope.onAddressAutocompleteChange();
        }, true);
    }
    return CustomerdataTabCtrl;
})();

/*
ANGULAR DIRECTIVE
*/
angular.module("ngAutocomplete", [])
    .directive('ngAutocomplete', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                options: '=',
                details: '=',
                address: '='
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                //options for autocomplete
                var opts;
                var watchEnter = false;
                //convert options provided to opts
                var initOpts = function () {

                    opts = {};
                    if (scope.options) {

                        if (scope.options.watchEnter !== true) {
                            watchEnter = false
                        } else {
                            watchEnter = true
                        }

                        if (scope.options.types) {
                            opts.types = [];
                            opts.types.push(scope.options.types);
                            scope.gPlace.setTypes(opts.types)
                        } else {
                            scope.gPlace.setTypes([])
                        }

                        if (scope.options.bounds) {
                            opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds;
                            scope.gPlace.setBounds(opts.bounds)
                        } else {
                            scope.gPlace.setBounds(null)
                        }

                        if (scope.options.country) {
                            opts.componentRestrictions = {
                                country: scope.options.country
                            };
                            scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(opts.componentRestrictions);
                        } else {
                            scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(null);
                        }
                    }
                };

                if (scope.gPlace == undefined) {
                    scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {});
                }

                google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function () {
                    var result = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        if (result.address_components !== undefined) {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.address = parseGoogleResponse(result.address_components);
                                scope.details = result;
                                controller.$setViewValue(element.val());
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            if (watchEnter) {
                                getPlace(result)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                //function to get retrieve the autocompletes first result using the AutocompleteService
                var getPlace = function (result) {
                    ...                    
                };


                var parseGoogleResponse = function(components) {
                    var result = {};

                    for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
                        var addressType = components[i].types[0];
                        result[addressType] = components[i]['long_name'];
                    }

                    return result;
                };


                controller.$render = function () {
                    var location = controller.$viewValue;
                    element.val(location);
                };

                //watch options provided to directive
                scope.watchOptions = function () {
                    return scope.options
                };
                scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function () {
                    initOpts()
                }, true);
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerdataTabCtrl">
<input type="text" id="customerdata_quick_auto_address" name="customerdata_quick_auto_address" class="form-control input-sm" ng-autocomplete ng-model="AddressAutocomplete" options="AddressAutocompleteOptions" details="AddressAutocompleteDetails" address="AddressAutocompleteAddress" />
{{AddressAutocompleteAddress.route}}
</div>
```

Like I said the view outputs the correct result, but the controller watch does only fire on init once, but then never again, but it is the same fu.... variable. The view {{AddressAutocompleteAddress.route}} uses the controller scope variable, I'm getting really crazy!

Kind regards

Comment: This snippet goes deeper than Inception.

Comment: LOL, jeah I'm sorry about that, like I said, the controller is generated by TypeScript, so it's only a "namespace".

Comment: I haven't read through everything but the generated code might be messing with you, try to define everything in vanilla JS.

Comment: But like I said, the view output works like charm!

Comment: Do you think it's got anything to do with the fact that you're calling your scope variable ngModel, when angular already has a directive with the same name? Have you tried changing to something else?

Comment: The directive is to 98% from Githup, I just modified it a bit. I can try this.

Comment: No, tested it (Comment it out). Same result

Comment: So, changed the controller now to vanilla JS, and same issue! ;(

Comment: Where do you set the controller?

Comment: I haven't looked at this issue in detail but it seems to be a misunderstanding as to how scope works.  Have you read this document https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes ?

Comment: I leave the controller out, because you can't do anything wrong on that :) But now I inserted it to the snipped.

Comment: This is the first time I worked with a directive, and this is copied, so until now I use only my local scope in the controller.
If you see the error, please tell me.

Comment: yo homie, this code is cray cray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, this is a problem with the scoping of the variables.  The directive's isolate scope is making it's own instance of the `AddressAutocompleteAddress` variable since it is a "primitive" variable.  The way to fix this is to use the "." (dot) notation.

What I would probably do to your code is to create an object called `AddressAutocomplete` and then add your other variables to that object.

```
function CustomerdataTabCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.AddressAutocomplete = {};
    $scope.AddressAutocomplete.Text = '';
    $scope.AddressAutocomplete.Options = {};
    $scope.AddressAutocomplete.Options.watchEnter = true;
    $scope.AddressAutocomplete.Details = '';
    $scope.AddressAutocomplete.Address = null;
    ...
}
```

And in your html:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerdataTabCtrl">
    <input type="text" id="customerdata_quick_auto_address" 
       name="customerdata_quick_auto_address"
       class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="AddressAutocomplete.Text" 
       ng-autocomplete options="AddressAutocomplete.Options"
       details="AddressAutocomplete.Details" address="AddressAutocomplete.Address" />
    {{AddressAutocomplete.Address.route}}
</div>
```

Just remember to update the way you use the variables in your controller.  Also I don't see where you use the `ng-model` variable in your directive so I'm not sure why you are using it there.

One more thing,  you really should not use the `ng-` prefix for your directives, that is a reserved prefix for directives from the AngularJs library.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please also post, what I have to change in the directive code?
Because now, without changes it doesn't work anymore, also the view update does not work anymore.

Comment: Where do you get the information from, that this hole thing does not work with "primitiv" variables?

Comment: @SharpNoiZy I posted a link in a comment to your question, but here it is again [Understanding Scopes in AngularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)